# Using HashTable to pass data between Activities

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am building a Note taking app for Android.
To ease the pain of sharing values (data/objects) between activities, I wrote an **IntentHelper** class which stores `<key,object>` pair in `HashTable`.

```
public class IntentHelper {
    private static IntentHelper _instance;
    private static Hashtable<String, Object> _hash;


    private IntentHelper() {
        _hash = new Hashtable<>();
    }

    public static IntentHelper getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new IntentHelper();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public static void addObjectForKey(Object obj, String key) {
        getInstance()._hash.put(key, obj);
    }

    public static Object getObjectForKey(String key) {
        IntentHelper helper = getInstance();
        Object data = helper._hash.get(key);
        helper._hash.remove(key);
        helper = null;
        return data;
    }
}
```

If you look at the IntentHelper class, it also removes the `<key, object>` pair from the HashTable after retrieving it. This was just for optimization.

`Note` is a Java POJO with `String` member variables.

Using the IntentHelper, I am passing along `Note` object between 2 Activities, but when I run the app it crashes with error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {co.kodr.note/co.kodr.note.activity.NoteViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String co.kodr.note.model.Note.getNoteDescription()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String co.kodr.note.model.Note.getNoteDescription()' on a null object reference
                      at co.kodr.note.activity.NoteViewActivity.reDrawView(NoteViewActivity.java:47)
                      at co.kodr.note.activity.NoteViewActivity.onResume(NoteViewActivity.java:54)
```

And when I debug the app, I can see that the `Note` object retrieved from IntentHelper is NOT null. Here are the 2 activities:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Note note;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.single_note_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        reDrawNoteList();
    }

    private void reDrawNoteList() {

        Cursor cursor = Utils.readFromDatabase(this, Constants.SELECT_ALL_NOTES);

        ListView notesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.noteList);
        NoteCursorAdapter noteCursorAdapter = new NoteCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
        notesList.setAdapter(noteCursorAdapter);

        notesList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                note = (Note) view.getTag();
                startNoteViewActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        reDrawNoteList();
    }

    private void startNoteViewActivity(){
        IntentHelper.getInstance().addObjectForKey(note, Constants.SINGLE_NOTE);
        Intent note_view_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoteViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(note_view_intent);
    }
}
```

**NoteViewActivity**

```
public class NoteViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Note note;
    private CustomTextView noteTitle;
    private CustomTextView noteText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.single_note_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        noteTitle = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_NoteDescription);
        noteText = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_NoteText);

        reDrawView();

    }

    private void reDrawView(){

        note = (Note) IntentHelper.getObjectForKey(Constants.SINGLE_NOTE);

        noteTitle.setText(note.getNoteDescription());
        noteText.setText(note.getNoteText());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        reDrawView();
    }
}
```

I know that the issue is somehow around removing `<key, value>` pair while retrieving it, because I can stop the app from crashing by commenting out:

```
helper._hash.remove(key);
```

The issue is happening on fresh launch of app (`onCreate`) as well as `OnResume`. I can see why it is happening in `OnResume` but not on `OnCreate`.

Can someone please explain the actual issue here?

Comment: A singleton hashtable seems like a poor idea. Use a parcelable to correctly move data between intents

Comment: @cricket_007 any specific issue with singleton hashtable?

Comment: Singleton is an anti-pattern for what you're trying to do. Plus, you already have the database, so you've got a persistent layer there

Comment: @cricket_007 persistent layer is not recommended to save data to be shared between Intents.

Comment: Thats not really my point. You're using the singleton pattern wrong anyway. `getInstance()` should be called once in the class you need it, so `IntentHelper.getInstance()` one time, then on **that instance** you call `getObjectForKey`. Your current code is really pointless for the `_instance` variable as the `_hash` itself is static also

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you remove the object when `onCreate` happens, you then try to start other activities or come back to some activity using that key in the hashtable. At which point, the object is gone from the hashtable.

You can use `Parcelable` objects and use the `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods within an Activity, or `Intent.putExtra` to pass around `Parcelable`s